# Difference between update_attributes and setting to nil directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Is there a difference between the following two snippets for this given class?

```
class MyObjectClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

# Snippet 1
my_obj.address = nil
my_obj.save

# Snippet 2
my_obj.update_attributes {address: nil}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes they are essentially doing the same thing if you're talking solely about setting the address field to nil.

Comment: That's what I thought. What about my_obj.update_attributes {address_id: nil}  ?  Will this run into problems with how the relationship saves?  We've noticed some flakiness that we can't seem to nail down.

Comment: What you've got here is pretty straightforward and not likely the root cause of your issues. What sort of flakiness are you seeing?

Comment: Sometimes address won't clear out when only setting the foreign key field to nil and not the address accessor to nil too.

Comment: Typically you want to work with the accessors as much as possible and leave the foreign key field out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between them at all. If you had used my_obj.update_attributes(params[:my_object]) then Spikes answer would be correct as you are dealing with mass assignment, however in snippet 2 you are only updating the address attribute so they are identical.

Answer (score -1):

Snippet 2 is subject to mass assignment security. [More details are in the Rails security guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) Snippet 2 also [skips validations and callbacks.](http://marklunds.com/articles/one/333)

Comment: Snippet 2 does not skip validations and callbacks.  The validation/callback skippage only happens when using the singular `update_attribute`, not `update_attributes`.

Comment: Also its not subject to mass assignment because hes only passing the address as a param